# qemu apt-get error failed to fetch

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, qemu

I am running a qemu terminal and trying to scp files into it. In qemu, I am running a linaro release. I have configured /etc/network/interfaces with

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I have also executed,

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Still apt-get update,  apt-get update --fix-missing, and apt-get install openssh-server commands lead to errors such as,

```
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe armel Packages 404 not found
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dist/natty-security/main/binary-armel/Packages
```

Comment: I figured out that without scp i can simply cp files into the image. just mount the image at /mnt. them cp filename /mnt/root